# Web page behaves strangely

Tags: css

Have a look at the following site http://www.soe.gr.

- The whole page has been built with CSS Page Builder Magic 2 (projectseven.com).
- Every button is a link to a different .html page.

However, I do not know why every button press creates a flash effect in the page, the background changes instantly color and generally it gives an impression of abnormal operation. I have not met any site with such behavior except some pages inside projectseven site.
Do you have any idea why that happens? Is it something wrong with Page Builder Magic approach?
I am new to Web Development world and I want to know if there is any problem with these guys.

Thank you very much

Comment: Is the issue you can "see" the delay when the images load? However, since they load quickly they appear to flicker (or flash)

Comment: @DaveRook If that is the problem then I think that I preloader would do the trick.

Comment: I don't see anything strange, actually (Chrome, Mac OS X 10.6).

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs - I couldn't agree more, great suggestion but the OP has used a tool to make it so I have no idea if feasible.

Answer (score 2):

I checked it out, it doesn't behave abnormally at all for all those effects you have there, I checked out the size of one of the images it is about 250kb, then imagine the other images which I assume are of the same size, and they are all going to be loaded when the page loads, you definitely should expect some effect

Comment: try reducing the size of your images, and minimize the use of fancy changing images

Comment: Although we live in a world of super fast internet etc, I still try and keep my sites to a below 200kb (per page)! +1